# x86-64 Linux No seg fault on stack misalignment

Tags: linux, x86-64

I'm just working through Nick Desaulniers: [Let's Write Some X86-64](http://nickdesaulniers.github.io/blog/2014/04/18/lets-write-some-x86-64/) File h4.s:

```
.text
.globl main
 main:
#  subq $8, %rsp
movq $0, %rdi
call _exit
```

He's running on a Mac and says running the above will give a segmentation fault. I'm running on opensuse 13.1 just calling

```
gcc h4.s
```

to compile and link. I don't get a seg fault when the stack pointer is adjusted or when the line is commented out. Does anyone know why not? Doesn't the SP need to be aligned to a 16 byte boundary?

Comment: The Linux kernel does not require nor impose alignment of the stack pointer to a 128-bit (giant)word boundary.

Comment: Hi Rich, Sami has the correct answer above.

Comment: The kernel doesn't use the user-space stack pointer so that's completely irrelevant.  The real answer is that the `_exit` wrapper function happens not to do any `movaps` to/from the stack, just `mov $60, %eax` / `syscall`.  Unlike for example scanf: [glibc scanf Segmentation faults when called from a function that doesn't align RSP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51070716)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The x86-64 System V ABI requires the stack pointer to be 8 mod 16 bytes on entry to a routine (16B aligned before the `call`, 16+8 after with a return address pushed on the stack).

Only SSE instructions require this (like `movaps` / `movdqa`), which most library functions happen not to use.  Especially simple ones like `_exit` could be as simple as `mov $231, %eax` / `syscall`.

However, if the stack is misaligned and someone at some point wants to do something that is based on the assumption that they have a 16B aligned stack.  For example, issue an aligned xmm instructions like "movdqa [rsp],...", then you can get an actual seg fault.  Or hypothetically some other error for some other kind of assumption of stack alignment.

In summary : Simply misaligning the stack before a call will usually not fault.

Just like C undefined behaviour, it's not required to fail if you violate the rules, but it *can* fail.  And what happens to work now might break in the future or on other systems.

Compilers *are* allowed to use SSE anywhere to copy 16 bytes at a time to / from local variables, [because of the ABI guarantee](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49391001/why-does-system-v-amd64-abi-mandate-a-16-byte-stack-alignment), and because x86-64 guarantees at least SSE2.

For example, [glibc scanf Segmentation faults when called from a function that doesn't align RSP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51070716/glibc-scanf-segmentation-faults-when-called-from-a-function-that-doesnt-align-r) - modern builds of glibc include a `movaps` to copy 16 bytes at once to a local struct or array.  Older builds of glibc didn't require stack alignment (when you properly set AL=0).